# Does a database index work in reverse?

Tags: database, sql-server-2008, indexing

Given a database table example:

```
ID
Name
DateOfBirth
```

Say I wanted to create an index on date of birth, I might add the index on `DateOfBirth ascending`.  If my code now queries on DOB ascending, it will run nice and fast.

However, are databases intelligent enough to use the index in reverse, i.e, if I queried `orderby DateOfBirth descending` would it still be able to utilise that index, or should I create another one specifically for descending ordering?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The index pages form a doubly linked list as shown below with pointers to both the next and previous page.

[image]

Thus SQL Server can traverse the index both backwards and forwards. The Scan direction [is shown in the properties of the execution plan](http://sqlblog.com/blogs/paul_white/archive/2011/02/17/so-is-it-a-seek-or-a-scan.aspx).

Where the `Asc`/`Desc` becomes important is in composite indexes.

If the index was defined as `ID ASC, Name ASC, DateOfBirth ASC` this would still require a sort for the query `ORDER BY ID ASC, Name DESC, DateOfBirth ASC` for example.

Note that you may have more composite indexes than you realise as well as a non unique non clustered index [will have the clustered index key value added to its key](http://sqlblog.com/blogs/kalen_delaney/archive/2010/03/07/more-about-nonclustered-index-keys.aspx).